# How can I group the data of a mapped object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, mapping

```
const data = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "monkey",
        category: {
            id: "2",
            color: "blue"
        }
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "cat",
        category: {
            id: "1",
            color: "red"
        }
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        name: "snake",
        category: {
            id: "2"
            color: "blue",
        }
    },
    {
        id: "4",
        name: "elephant",
        category: {
            id: "1"
            color: "green"
        }
    }
];
```

This is my code:

```
return (data.map(obj => obj.category ? `color: ${obj.category.color} , name:   ${obj.name}` : `${obj.name}`)).join('<br>');
```

The output is:

```
color: blue,  name: monkey
color: red,   name: cat
color: blue,  name: snake
color: green, name: elephant
```

What I am trying to do is group the output by category would be:

```
color: blue,  name: monkey
color: blue,  name: snake
color: green, name: elephant
color: red,   name: cat
```

This is my approach:

```
return (data.map(data.groupBy(obj.category, "category"),obj => obj.category ? `color: ${obj.category.color} , name:   ${obj.name}` : `${obj.name}`)).join('<br>').sort();
```

But I get the error

> obj is not defined

Comment: where do you have `groupBy` from?

Comment: @NinaScholz https://www.consolelog.io/group-by-in-javascript/

Comment: Why don't you just Sort the array by category first before console.logging everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the data first:

```
data.sort((a,b) => Number(a.category.id) - Number(b.category.id));
```

Then do your operation for logging them all or whatever

Comment: I am trying to understand your code. Why do I subtract category ids. How is this working?

Comment: the Sort function on an Array runs a callback on pairs of elements inside the array, `a` and `b` -- if the callback returns a negative number, it puts `a` before `b`, and if it's a positive number, the reverse (unless I got that backwards, that's possible). So by subtracting the categories, we're just telling it to use the categories to decide which comes first, a or b

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` method to group in one object and then you can create string with `map` and `join` from `Object.values()`.

```js
const data = [{"id":"1","name":"monkey","category":{"id":"2","color":"blue"}},{"id":"2","name":"cat","category":{"id":"1","color":"red"}},{"id":"3","name":"snake","category":{"id":"2","color":"blue"}},{"id":"4","name":"elephant","category":{"id":"1","color":"green"}}]

const group = data.reduce((r, {name, category: {color}}) => {
  const str = `color: ${color}, name: ${name}`
  r[color] = (r[color] || []).concat(str)
  return r;
}, {})

const res = Object.values(group)
  .map(e => e.join('\n'))
  .join('\n')

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get `result` using [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Also notice the use of [unary plus (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) to cast the `id` to numeric value

Code:

```js
const data = [{id: "1",name: "monkey",category: {id: "2",color: "blue"}},{id: "2",name: "cat",category: {id: "1",color: "red"}},{id: "3",name: "snake",category: {id: "2",color: "blue",}},{id: "4",name: "elephant",category: {id: "1",color: "green"}}];
const result = data
  .sort((a,b) => +b.category.id - +a.category.id)
  .map(obj => `color: ${obj.category.color}, name: ${obj.name}`);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the grouping function with a callback fo rgrouping with a function for nested properties and get the result in a flat array. Then add your style to the array for the output.

```js
Array.prototype.groupBy = function (prop) {
    return this.reduce(function (groups, item) {
        const val = typeof prop === 'function' ? prop(item) : item[prop];
        groups[val] = groups[val] || [];
        groups[val].push(item);
        return groups;
    }, {})
};

const
    data = [{ id: "1", name: "monkey", category: { id: "2", color: "blue" } }, { id: "2", name: "cat", category: { id: "1", color: "red" } }, { id: "3", name: "snake", category: { id: "2", color: "blue", } }, { id: "4", name: "elephant", category: { id: "1", color: "green" } }],
    grouped = Object
        .values(data.groupBy(o => o.category.id))
        .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b]),
    result = Object
        .values(grouped)
        .map(obj => `color: ${obj.category.color} , name:   ${obj.name}`).join('<br>');

console.log(grouped);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```